# To find realted data of table1 in table2

Tags: php, mysql

Table1 Has Some data as Categories

[image: Here is my table1]

Table2 Has Some data Which is Realated to table1 Categories
[image: Here is my table2]

and the relation between two tables is cat_id from table1 and cat_ids from table2.

What I want is? 
I need to display all fields in table1 and from table2 I need only the related content i.e id's present in cat_id(table1) and cat_ids(table2)

I am using a query like this `select c.* ,cc.* from news_categories cc,  news_content c where cc.cat_id = c.cat_ids group by cc.cat_id` this gives only common data from table1 and table2.. i need common data and all categories from table1
can anyone help me?

Comment: fyi, i'm assuming realtion is relation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JOIN` instead.

```sql
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.content_id)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.cat_ids = t1.cat_id
GROUP BY t1.cat_id
```

Comment: how can i get those group_contact() id's data

Comment: @user1929491 Can you please specifically mention which column you want to fetch?

Comment: i mean all column's related to the id's grouped by Group_contact() for table2

Comment: Yea i got It.. Thank u for this usefull query.

Comment: is there any option of changing this query by without using group_concat()

Answer (score 0):

This is for all fields of both tables...

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.cat_id = Table2.cat_ids
```

This is for all fields of Table1 and Content field of Table2...

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.full_content
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.cat_id = Table2.cat_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use outer join and this case left join .. Have a look at [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)